# How should I set up a reverse proxy with nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I must configure a reverse proxy with nginx installed on the machine, to redirect the connections to the Docker containers. Is there a problem if my reverse proxy is also a container instead of physically installing on the machine? Which form is the most suitable?

Comment: I'd say both forms are equally suitable. You could also install nginx in your existing Docker container. As long as there is an nginx instance running _somewhere_.

Comment: Got it! I took a course that taught me how to install on the physical machine, and redirect to the container, but I didn't say why my reverse proxy couldn't be a container either. Thanks, your answer helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did several searches, and I found no problems when using the reverse proxy with nginx installed on the physical machine, or using a container, so I chose to use a container.